# loop object over canvas JS P5

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I use JS P5.
I've created a function that creates an ellipse.
I want to loop this ellipse over the whole canvas with some distance between each ellipse.

I didn't use a normal ellipse because I want to put another function on each ellipse later.
So my question how to use a for loop and a nested loop on an object that I create.

This is my code, I have a random way here, but I want is the exact distance, like a grid over the whole page.

Like this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGrD1.png)

```js
let shapes = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++){
    let x = random(width);
    let y = random(height);

    shapes[i] = new shape(x,y,20);
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  for (let i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++){
    shapes[i].display();
  }
}


function shape(tx, ty, ts) {
  this.x = tx;
  this.y = ty;
  this.size = ts;
  this.angle = 0;

  this.update = function(mx, my) {
    this.angle = atan2(my - this.y, mx - this.x);
  };

  this.display = function() {
    push();
    fill(153, 204, 0);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
    pop();
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited answer:**

```
let shapes = [];

function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 600);
    for(var x=0;x<width;x+=30){
        for(var y=0;y<height;y+=30){
            shapes.push(new shape(x,y,20));
        }
    }
}

function draw() {
    background(220);

    for (let i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++){
        shapes[i].display();
    }
}


function shape(tx, ty, ts) {
    this.x = tx;
    this.y = ty;
    this.size = ts;
    this.angle = 0;

    this.update = function(mx, my) {
        this.angle = atan2(my - this.y, mx - this.x);
    };

    this.display = function() {
        push();
        fill(153, 204, 0);
        ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
        pop();
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but what i need is to put this nested loop on my object..
I don't want to skip the objekt and just draw a normal ellipse.

Comment: Okay. Can you explain what exactly you are looking to make? Thanks.

Comment: What i mean is to put the nested loop on the shapes objekt, to create this resault.

Comment: Shapes is afunction that create an ellipse, and i want to use a nested loop n it...

Comment: If you see my code example you can see that i did it but with a random positions....what i want is to edit it to get the resault that you showed.

Comment: I've changed my answer. Can you see if it works now?

Comment: Thank you sooo much, this is exactly what I needed.